# Measurable, bounded, complex valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is not Hilbert

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H= \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ be the space of measurable, bounded, complex valued functions on $\mathbb{R};$ define

$$(f,g) =  \int_{\mathbb R} \dfrac{f(x)\bar g(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

I would like to see that this is not a Hilbert space. I found this problem [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595450/a-not-hilbert-space) but it is now closed and I don't understand the solution given..

Can you help me understand that solution or give a proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the earlier post this is not an inner product unless you identify two functions when they are equal almost everywhere. Let us assume that we have done that.

Let $f_n(x)=x^{1/3}$ if $0<x <n$ and $0$ for all other $x$. Let us show that this sequence is Cauchy. We have $\int \frac {|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^{2}} {1+x^{2}}dx=\int_n^{m} \frac {x^{2/3}} {1+x^{2}}$ if $n <m$. This last integral does not exceed $\int_n^{m} \frac 1 {x^{4/3}}dx=3(\frac 1{n^{1/3}}- \frac 1{m^{1/3}}) \to 0$. So we have proved that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy. Suppose this sequence converges to some $f$. Then $\int  {|f_n-f|^{2}} d\mu(x) \to 0$ where $\mu$ is defined by $\mu (E)=\int_E \frac  1{1+x^{2}}dx$. By a basic result in measure theory this implies that there is  a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ which converges almost everywhere (w.r.t $\mu$, hence also w.r.t Lebesgue measure). Now let $x>0$. Then $0<x <n_k$ for $k$ sufficiently large so we must have $f(x)=\lim f_{n_k}(x)= x^{1/3}$. But then $f$ is not bounded so it does not belong to the space under consideration.

Comment: Thanks, which is the "basic result in measure theory" you refer to in 7th line?

Comment: @wezapa If $f_n \to f$ in $L^{p}(\mu)$ then there is a subsequence  of $(f_n)$ which converge almost everywhere to $f$ w.r.t.t $\mu$.

Comment: how can i prove that?

Comment: @wezapa Do you know that convergence in measure implies almost every where convergence for a subsequence? If you know that fact then you can just note that $\mu (x:|f_n(x)-f(x)| >\epsilon) \leq \frac  1{\epsilon^{p}} \int |f_n-f|^{p} d\mu \to 0$

Comment: yes, thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Hint: find an unbounded function $f$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^2/(1+x^2)\; dx  < \infty$, and show that its truncations form a Cauchy sequence  that does not have
a limit in $H$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would prefer a solution I can study as an example, rather than a hint.

Comment: Your hint is precisely the content of the answer already given in the linked question. And my question is precisely to have a better explanation of that! :)